# How to get Google Analytics using user provided web id?

Tags: plugin, overrides, google-analytics

I am working on a project similar to [filippa.com](https://flippa.com/).

In the process of registering a website, the user will input her/his web id, something like `XX-XXXX-X`.

I need to implement a plugin in my item view override to get the website analytics from Google Analytics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a very involved process of authentication and pulling data from the Google Analytics API: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/ 
You might try playing around with their Explorer tool as well: https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/account-explorer/ 
I am almost positive you cannot pull data without some type of authentication.  There are several Joomla components that will pull Analytics in a dashboard, but they are set to show data for one site and require setting up secret keys, etc.  
You might check out some of the PHP Google Analytics scripts from CodeCanyon, but those require authentication as well: https://codecanyon.net/category/php-scripts?as=0&referrer=homepage&tags=google%20analytics&term=google%20analytics

Comment: Thanks. is there any way to get simple traffic reports without authorization? cause a seller registers to this application and buyers need to see this GA-Reports, so the buyers do not have authorization information.

Comment: and is there any plugin for it?

Comment: I updated my answer